# XML validation in Java - extra closing tag >

Tags: java, xml

I've been trying to write junit test cases that figure check the syntax of an XML file, make sure all tags are closed, etc.

I am currently Using a dom parser in the test, as it throws an exception on invalid XML but it isn't working when I have an extra closing tag for my XML
eg: if i have

```
 private static final String OM_APPLICATION_STRG = "<abc>**>**\r\n" + 
            "</abc>\r\n" + 
            "";
```

instead of

```
private static final String OM_APPLICATION_STRG = "<abc>\r\n" + 
        "</abc>\r\n" + 
        "";
```

Please let me know if there is any other way to test xml validity including extra closing tag

Comment: I'm not sure which parser you are using, but in my experience JAVA DOM parsers are extremely inflexible as far as rubbish XML goes, so I think it's safe to assume that if the DOM parser doesn't throw an exception, the document is valid XML markup.

Answer (score 3):

An "extra closing tag" is not a concept that exists. It is just a "greater-than" symbol in a text node in an XML file, and it's perfectly valid to have them. You don't need to check for them in your validator.

For example, this is completely valid xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xml>></xml>
```

Comment: Thank you. If there is no concept like an extra closing tag and it is a greater than symbol that why do I get an error when there is an extra opening tag "<" .... example 'private static final String OM_APPLICATION_STRG = "<abc>\r\n" + 
        "<</abc>\r\n" + 
        "";   '

Comment: It's because an opening smaller than symbol and a closing greater than symbol are different things. The first smaller-than character starts and xml tag and it is not allowed to have a smaller-than tag as part of the xml tag name. but a greater-than symbol can freely occur inside a text node.

Answer (score 2):

May be there is another way —— SchemaFactory

You can define a .xsd file for your xml string, then use SchemaFactory to validate your xml string by the .xsd file.
Like this example

```
   String xml = xmlFile.toString();
   try {
      URL schema = Resources.getResource("/XXX.xsd");
      Validator validator = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema").newSchema(schema)
            .newValidator();
      Source source = new StreamSource(new CharArrayReader(xml.toCharArray()));
      validator.validate(source);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // the xml is not valid for your .xsd defination
   }
```

Comment: How would this detect extra greater than symbols? (like the OP asked) Since, they're *not* invalid in XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<abc>**>**</abc>
```

is valid XML.

What you need to do is define a schema for XML and set [restrictions](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_restriction.asp) on the content of text nodes.

A simple example would be `schema.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="abc">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[\sa-zA-Z0-9\*]*" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The regular expression

```
[\sa-zA-Z0-9\*]*
```

defines the set of character allowed in the text node inside of the element `<abc>`

The following document would validate

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<abc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
    hello ** world
</abc>
```

If you add a `>` charcter

```
hello ** > ** world
```

the XML will no longer validate against the schema.

For validating against a schema see `RomanticNerd`'s answer.